# imported perl variable imports with no value

Tags: perl, exporter

**SOLVED:** As it turns out, my problem was rooted in the fact that I was **not** putting a $ in front of DEBUGVAR in the @EXPORT_OK assignment and the "use config_global qw(config DEBUGVAR);" line. Since it raises no error, I had no way to know this was the issue. So, the fix is to place the proper syntax in front of your variables at these points.

So I am trying to get the hang of writing and importing perl modules. I don't know why it was made so difficult to do this, but I am having a great deal of trouble with this seeimingly trivial task. Here is the contents of my module:

```
package global_config;
use strict;

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(DEBUGVAR);

our ($DEBUGVAR);

our $DEBUGVAR = "Hello, World!";

return 1;
```

Here are the contents of my perl script that imports the module:

```
use strict;

use config_global qw(config, DEBUGVAR);
our %config;
our $DEBUGVAR;


print "variable imported with value: ".$DEBUGVAR;
```

The output is "variable imported with value:", and nothing else. My variable appears to be losing it's value. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: After fiddling around a bit, and turning warnings on, I have isolated the issue to being that $DEBUGVAR is never actually imported. When I use it via $config_global:DEBUGVAR, it works as expected. The issue now is that it is not importing into the namespace. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues:

- You should not use a comma in the `qw()` syntax. The `qw` takes each whitespace separated phrase and puts it in an array element.

These two are the same:

```
my @bar = qw(foo bar barfu);          #No commas!
my @bar = ("foo", "bar", "barfu");    #Commas Required
```

- If you're exporting a variable, you need to put the [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) in front of it.

You have:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(DEBUGVAR);
```

It should be:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw($DEBUGVAR);
```

- You should use the newer Exporter syntax:

Here's the newer Exporter Syntax:

```
package global_config;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';   #Not "require". No need for "@ISA"

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(DEBUGVAR);

our $DEBUGVAR = "Hello, World";

1;    #Makes no real difference, but you shouldn't say "return 1". Just standard.
```

- Finally, what are you doing exporting variables? That's just a bad practice.

  - Exporting anything is now questioned -- even functions. It pollutes the user's namespace. (At least you're using `@EXPORT_OKAY`). Take a look at [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html). It uses fully qualified package names for its subroutines by default.
  - The variable in question is accessible via the full package name `$global_config::DEBUGVAR`, so there's no real need to export it.
  - What if everybody did it? Yes, you last heard of this excuse in kindergarten, but it applies here. Imagine if several modules exported `$DEBUGVAR`.

There are several ways around your quandary, but the best is to use object oriented Perl to help set this variable, and even allow users to change it.

```
package MyPackage;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $debug = shift;  #Optional Debug Value

   my $self = {};
   bless $self, $class;

   if (not defined $debug) {
      $debug = "Hello, world!";

   $self->Debug($debug);
   return $self;
}

sub Debug {
   my $self  = shift;
   my $debug = shift;

   if (defined $debug) {
      $self->{DEBUG} = $debug;
   }
   return $debug;
}

1;
```

To use this module, I simply create a new object, and Debug will be set for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyPackage               #No exporting needed

#Create an object w/ Debug value;
my $obj = MyPackage->new;   #Debug is the default.
say $obj->Debug;            #Prints "Hello, world!"

# Change the value of Debug
$obj->Debug("Foo!");
say $obj->Debug;            #Now prints "Foo!"

#Create a new object with a different default debug
$obj2 = MyPackage->new("Bar!");
say $obj2->Debug;           #Print "Bar!";
```

This solves several issues:

- It allows multiple values of debug because each object now has its own values
- There is no worry about namespace pollution or accessing package variables. Again, all you need is contained in the object itself.
- It's easier to debug issues since the complexity is hidden inside the objects themselves.
- It's the new preferred method, so you might as well get use to the syntax and be able to read object oriented Perl code. You'll be seeing it more and more.

Answer (score 1):

While exporting variables from a package isn't necessarily a recommended practice, to do so, you need to use the actual name of the variable you are exporting.  In this case it is `$DEBUGVAR` and not `DEBUGVAR` which would be the name of a subroutine.

In the script using the config module, you do not need to declare the `$DEBUGVAR` variable as `our`, since imported variables are exempt from strict vars.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a comma here:

```
use config_global qw(config, DEBUGVAR);
```

Also, you aren't exporting config, so it might work better as:

```
use config_global qw(DEBUGVAR);
```

I'd also remove the last `our $DEBUGVAR;` since it might set it to undef (or at least put it before the "use" line) -- I am not sure about this though.

Answer (score 0):

You have gotten the name mixed up, it looks like:

```
use config_global ...

package global_config;
```

Though one would think that would issue warnings. Unless you are not using warnings...?

ETA:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw($DEBUGVAR);
                    ^
```

Also, you have two declarations on that variable. You really need to use warnings when debugging, otherwise, you'll never get anywhere.

Comment: Haha yes. Wow. Good catch. I did just fix it, but unfortunately I still have the same problem. =/